# How to deploy a few wars to root tomcat?

Tags: docker, tomcat, path, root

I need a few deployed war on server and it 
should look like:

```
localhost:8080/war1/run_app1
localhost:8080/war2/run_app2
```

I tried such approach:

```
FROM tomcat
MAINTAINER user1

#VOLUME /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

RUN ["rm", "-fr", "/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT"]
ADD /src/main/docker/run_app1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/war1/

COPY /src/main/docker/run_app1.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/war1/ROOT.war

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

But it's not working... Any idea how to implement such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple, just rename the WAR files!

taking your .war file example:

If you want war1.war file to run as "localhost:8080/war1/run_app1" just rename it:

```
mv war1.war war1#run_app1.war
```

and copy this file to `TOMCAT_DIR/webapps/`

Accordingly you can change the commandline (filenames) in your docker.

Please let me know if you have any doubt or you are looking for a different solution.

Thanks,
Nishant